# Translation (of my input) in Careers profile

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I wonderd what are best practices for a multi language Careers Profile e.g. one that will be discovered well by German and US Companies?

Should i translate my Education Degree and my Responsibilities etc. in each field, so that each field contains a block for each language? (something like "German: Ich war verantwortlich für... / English: I was responsible for...")?

Or is there another way (maybe two Profiles)?

Comment: +1 I'm wondering the same, as Spanish native speaker, it's difficult make a more attractive profile on Careers.